# How do I align the image and the search bar in one line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added `margin-left` by `20%` on my form, because I want my logo to fit in but apparently, the extra spaces are still there, thus my logo is above the search bar. I'm using twitter Bootstrap
[image]

How do I remove that orange box, because apparently there is still space there.

To illustrate

[image]

I want that pink color space to disappear so that my logo could be at that position

Here is the JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m2q6fmmr/

make the result box bigger, to see the full example

```css
.sbx-amazon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 39px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.sbx-amazon__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sbx-amazon__input {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease, background .4s ease;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease, background .4s ease;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 75px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

.sbx-amazon__input::-webkit-search-decoration, .sbx-amazon__input::-webkit-search-cancel-button, .sbx-amazon__input::-webkit-search-results-button, .sbx-amazon__input::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}

.sbx-amazon__input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #e6e6e6;
}

.sbx-amazon__input:focus, .sbx-amazon__input:active {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #FFBF58;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.sbx-amazon__input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.sbx-amazon__input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.sbx-amazon__input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.sbx-amazon__input::placeholder {
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.sbx-amazon__submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  background-color: #ffbf58;
  padding: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: inherit;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.sbx-amazon__submit::before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
}

.sbx-amazon__submit:hover, .sbx-amazon__submit:active {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sbx-amazon__submit:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.sbx-amazon__submit svg {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: #202F40;
}

.sbx-amazon__reset {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 54px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sbx-amazon__reset:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.sbx-amazon__reset svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

.sbx-amazon__input:valid ~ .sbx-amazon__reset {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: sbx-reset-in;
          animation-name: sbx-reset-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .15s;
          animation-duration: .15s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sbx-reset-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes sbx-reset-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><span><img src="/img/.png" style="width: 10%; padding: 0"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-search-11" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
      <path d="M15.553 31.106c8.59 0 15.553-6.963 15.553-15.553S24.143 0 15.553 0 0 6.963 0 15.553s6.963 15.553 15.553 15.553zm0-3.888c6.443 0 11.665-5.222 11.665-11.665 0-6.442-5.222-11.665-11.665-11.665-6.442 0-11.665 5.223-11.665 11.665 0 6.443 5.223 11.665 11.665 11.665zM27.76 31.06c-.78-.78-.778-2.05.004-2.833l.463-.463c.783-.783 2.057-.78 2.834-.003l8.168 8.17c.782.78.78 2.05-.003 2.832l-.463.463c-.783.783-2.057.78-2.833.003l-8.17-8.167z"
      fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-clear-2" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M8.96 10L.52 1.562 0 1.042 1.04 0l.522.52L10 8.96 18.438.52l.52-.52L20 1.04l-.52.522L11.04 10l8.44 8.438.52.52L18.96 20l-.522-.52L10 11.04l-8.438 8.44-.52.52L0 18.96l.52-.522L8.96 10z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>

  <form novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return false;" class="searchbox sbx-amazon" style="margin-left: 20%">
    <div role="search" class="sbx-amazon__wrapper">
      <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search your product.." autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-amazon__input">
      <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="sbx-amazon__submit">
        <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-11"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="reset" title="Clear the search query." class="sbx-amazon__reset">
        <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-2"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: your fiddle is not working. When I press the nav button it do nothing

Comment: Try to drag the result box to the left, then you will see the full result

Comment: Can you please clear me which orange box you talk about, I don't see any orange box.

Comment: @imSayan if you inspect the form, you can see that the form take the space on the left as well. You can see the orange color box

Comment: @sinusGob  , now as i understood your question your search bar to be like this [click on this link to see the image](http://3.1m.yt/iEnwO6D.png)

Comment: @PavanBaddi Yeah, thats what I want, thanks

Comment: @sinusGob ok then i will get to you soon..

Comment: @sinusGob i have two images here one is in desktop view and the second is for mobile view . if you are satisfied with images then i'll post the answere.  [first image](http://2.1m.yt/ho3V6-S.png)   [second image](http://2.1m.yt/EQWa5LC.png)

Comment: @sinusGob  are you satisfied with images . tell me

Comment: @PavanBaddi The first image, can it be used with my example?

Comment: @sinusGob  the first image contains  logo area and search bar which your html code contains. In my code their are some radius but not a problem it can be styled

Comment: @PavanBaddi sure you can show the answer.

Comment: @sinusGob i have posted my answere

Answer (score 0):

so here is the answer. if you want to remove HOME link you can do that. The navbar color is in black. you can extend the length of your search bar will help of inspect element

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Search bar Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .fit-img{
        width:45px;
        height:50px;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:#f5f5f5;"><img src="Koala.jpg" class="fit-img"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:400px;border-radius:0;">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="border-radius:0;">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>


output image
```

[image: img output]

```
## Feel free to ask any question ##



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck0i6.png
```

Comment: how do i make the image fit the navbar? `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:#f5f5f5;"><img src="/img/.png"/></a>`

Comment: @sinusGob   than was my answer helped you